# Is there an app where I can construct a function curve and then I get the formulas or equivalent program code of the piecewise-defined function?

Tags: java, math, source-code, editor

Sometimes one need a mathematical function - for example for easing-function, or transition function, filter, etc - which properties are known, can be drawn or constructed by segments, can be defined constraints for it, for example monotonity in a given interval. And when I am ready with the function construction in the coordinate system, then I get preferably simple mathematical formulas or equivalent program code (C, Java, etc) for the function, which of course can be piecewise-defined, and also parametric or not, and their piecewise segments are connected at least in first order.

Comment: So you want to get the function from an image of the coresponding x,y diagram, or from a list of defined x,y values?

Comment: I would like to construct it from some curve segments, like Bezier curves, I think. I can't imagine another method.